# How can I get state(hover,active,..) of link by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Example I have a link with `id = "demo"`, now I want get a *state* of this link by *javascript*. I mean when the user mouses over this link, *javascript* can take state is `hover`.I try to research a lot but I don't see any functions to support this problem. Can you give me some ideas. Thanks for all

Comment: I'm not sure you can test for current state. Usually we'd act on _events_, such as hover, mouseover, etc.

Comment: Maybe revise to ask about your problem rather than your possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying, but javascript and css *(hover state)* do not speak with each other so you would need to manually get the state usign js events.

I believe mouse over event could suit your problem.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: This is really what I was looking for. Thank you very much